# Custom content type for SharePoint2013 Calendar?

Tags: content-type, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I've created custom content type for Calendar in SharePoint2013 that inherits from Event.

Now, im having issue with creating/adding a new item in the calendar.
SharePoint2013 does not want to save my changes when i create new event in the calendar. There are no errors thrown. I even created a new NewForm.aspx but still no luck.
If i roleback to the OOB content type, im able to create events.
Am i missing something here?? Does anybody else have any similar experience?
Thanks